# How to download a Image from a Path and save it as a BitmapImage

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Does anyone know, how to download a Image from a path like "C:/Data/Users/Public/Pictures/Camera Roll/Picture.jpg" (in a Windows Phone 8.1 Device) and save it as a BitmapImage? I tried it with this, but after that I don't know, how to save the StorageFile as a BitmapImage.

```
StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.CameraRoll;

StorageFile storageFile = await picturesFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
```

I hope someone can help me.

Cristian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a stream out of the file and open it via `SetSourceAsync` ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsourceasync.aspx)).

```
using (var stream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
  await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It works very well.